# How to import 3D models dynamically in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, import, 3d-model

I have been searching this for quite sometime but could not find an appropriate method. How to import 3D models in a WPF application at runtime when user selects a model. It can be built in any one of the popular 3D modelling software, 3DS max, Maya, Blender etc, not all. Any one of the formats .3DS, .MAX, .FBX, .obj etc is required to be imported.

If there are free libraries available for this, please mention them, and if i have to write the code myself, please guide how and where to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:  http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You may try to convert 3D objects in to XAML and use then in WPF. Most of the 3D modelling softwares has 3D Model to XAML plugins.

Try this as well.. (Commercial but good tool)
http://www.erain.com/products/zam3d/DefaultPDC.asp

and i also highly recommend [helixtoolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Good Luck.