# Can I use the Visual Studio Model Editor in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 3d-model

In an application I've written, I'd like to include a simple 3D model viewer, specifically FBX. I stumbled onto the Model Viewer inside Visual Studio itself, which looks like a great out-of-the-box solution to my problem. However, I can't find a way to get the Model Viewer inside my actual application. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: this may help too: https://github.com/helix-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The designer is just Visual Studio's, and can't be embedded into your own application.

There are alternatives though to incorporate the FBX file in your application. One of them is [the Autodesk FBX SDK](http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview). Alternatives for WPF can be found in [How to import 3D models dynamically in a WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9086201/993547).

Comment: Helix Toolkit seems very nice, sadly it doesn't allow FBX files.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Maybe the Autodesk FBX SDK? http://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview

Answer (score 0):

Using MeshContent tag in an Xaml file can import a .fbx file into your app as a .cmo file

The code is in the original Visual Studio 3d Starter Kit 1 & 2
Visual Studio 3D Sta1.sln for VS 2015
Visual Studio 3D Sta2.sln for VS 2015

This easily upgradable to 2019 19041 etc